# Find how many times changes maximum value in a list with reduce() (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reduce

Using `reduce()` function, I have to find how many times the maximum value of a list changes.
Here's my code, but I don't undestand why `count` remains to 0.

```
from functools import reduce

count = 0

heights = [10, 8, 11, 2, 1, 4, 13, 11]

reduce(lambda a, b: count + 1 if a < b else count + 0, heights, 0)

print(count)
```

Comment: "how many times the maximum value of a list changes" - what does this mean?

Comment: I assume it means, as you scan the list from beginning to end, the number of times you observe an element that is greater than any previous element.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel exactly. I correct my question

Comment: a>b always in condition

Comment: You never assign to ``count``. Why do you expect it to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `reduce` works is as follows:

- Take the default value (last parameter) and the first element of the sequence, and apply the provided function. Here, we take `0` and `10`, and compute: `count + 1 if 0 < 10 else count + 0`.
- Take the result from that operation, and apply the function to that and the second element, and so on.

You can't expect to solve the problem this way, because none of this actually *reassigns* `count` - it stays equal to `0` no matter how many times this iterates. Each application of the `lambda` just produces either `0` or `1`. Also, these `0` and `1` values are carried forward to the next step, instead of remembering the previous maximum value.

`reduce` is *not the right tool for this job*, *but* you can force it to work by computing a tuple of (maximum value seen so far, count) at each step. (You need to actually use the value returned by `reduce`, and not have any external `count`.)

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't actually undersand last sentence. Can you Help me with the code?

Comment: Imagine: we start with `(0, 0)` vs `10`, and compute `(10, 1)` because `0 < 10`. We will then be given that `(10, 1)` vs `8`, and should compute `10, 1` again. When we find a new maximum value, we need to replace the maximum, and increment the count.